# how to test 10G NIC in loopback for full throughput?

Tags: networking, 10gbethernet, iperf, jumboframes, 10gige

I am using 10G NIC x520-DA2 (which is x8 Lane)  in windows 10 Enterprise 64 Bit on DELL Optiplex 7080 Tower with Intel Core i7-10700 . X520-DA is installed on PCie slot 2 of optiplex 7080 that is PCIe x16.

I need to test x520-DA2 maximum throughput because I am doing an R&D project where I will be making 10G bridge core on FPGA which will be able to receive 10G traffic and transmit it back.

So for start I need to generate and receive 10G traffic. My test setup is, connect port 1 of x520-DA2 with port 2 x520-DA2 (Ethernet 3 & Ethernet 4 in picture) using SFP+ cable and run iperf3 with 8/16/32 parallel streams in client which results in 5-6 Gbps.
[Resource Usage jumbo packets disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qka14.png)
But when I enable jumbo packet for both ports I get 9.9Gbps using iperf with 6 parallel streams.
[Resource Usage jumbo packets enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IUBz.png)
I want to achieve 10G without using Jumbo packet. I almost enable disable all settings in NIC driver for both port but max I can achieve is 5.5Gbps.

Comment: Are you sure that the traffic is even hitting the NIC in this test configuration?

Comment: Yes I am sure, both pictures I linked show ethernet 4 is sending and Ethernet 3 is receiving. I also confirmed using wireshark

Comment: That NIC was launched 13 years ago!! Which interrupt-management/offloading options have you taken?

Comment: @Chopper3 Only settings for Interrupt in driver are Interrupt Moderation(Enabled) and Interrupt Moderation rate(Set to extreme). While I enabled and disabled IPSec Offload, IPv4 Checksum offload, Large Send offload V2 (IPv4), TCP checksum Offload (IPv4) and UDP checksum offload (IPv4).

Comment: @vidarlo@Chopper3
I disable antivirus and windows firewall now I get almost 9Gbps for few second and then 7 Gbps for few second and this behavior repeats. So now I think CPU is bottleneck because two three CPU core get 100% utilization